# Can "Mr", "Mrs", etc. be used with a first name?

Tags: formality, connotation, politeness, dialects, forms-of-address

Is it correct to use *Mr/Mrs* with a first name?

Comment: Please can you flesh out your question with a more detailed explanation, or example? I'm not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 19):

This is very common and proper in the southern United States. It is most often used by children speaking to adults they know well such as neighbors, friends' parents, more casual teachers, etc. Usually the adult will signal his or her preference on how to be addressed. Sometimes an adult (for example some teachers) will introduce themselves as Mr/Ms last name instead, which is also fine and wouldn't usually raise eyebrows.

It's also not uncommon for adults to use this construction between themselves. I've seen it when there's an age difference or a social status difference, but when using Mr/Ms last name would be too formal and distant sounding. Eg you see the elderly lady that's lived next door for years across the fence and say "Hi Ms. Diana!" Eg the younger person behind the register at the grocery you always go to says "see you next week Mr. Bob".

As Mr. England's post indicates, common usage dictates the rules, not the other way around. And in the South, this is very common and accepted. It can be a bit rude (or at least stiff and standoffish) not to use this construction if the adult being addressed prefers the first name.

Full disclosure: I grew up in southern Louisiana, but from what I've seen and heard, this is common to much of the southern US.

Comment: So it seems that the correct answer is "In general, no, that form is not used, but in some regional varieties it does happen". So if you are speaking such a variety then it's OK, but in general most people will think it sounds weird.

Comment: I've also heard salespeople in the southern U.S. do it as a way to establish rapport.

Comment: It's exceedingly common in central Indiana. I noticed it first among black service workers, then among Hispanic/Latinx folks. Since I am now older I get it a lot. It's pretty much the standard in nursing homes for staff to refer to their charges (and older coworkers) with the Mr./Miss. Definitely was something to get used to, because it seemed like such an anachronism.

Comment: I've seen Mr./Ms.+LastName used for teachers and Mr./Ms.+FristName used for those ranked less than a teacher at a school.

Answer (score 11):

We get into all sorts of difficulties when we consider whether this or that word or expression or construction is 'correct'. It's much more helpful to consider whether it's used, how widely and on what occasions. The address *Mr John Smith* is certainly found, but I take it your question is about whether it's possible to say or write *Mr John*. The answer to that is that it all depends. I can think of no circumstances in which I would do so myself, but I have been addressed as 'Mr Barrie', by those whose first language wasn't English.

Perhaps we could help you more if you said where you have seen or heard *Mr* or *Mrs* + first name.

**EDIT:**

The OED defines *Mr* (my emphasis) as:

> A title prefixed to the surname **or first name** of a man without a
>   higher, honorific, or professional title, or to any of various
>   designations of office .

The OED also reminds us that:

> In 19th century use, when Miss was prefixed to the surname alone, e.g.
>   Miss Smith, it normally indicated the eldest (unmarried) daughter of
>   the family; in referring to the others the forename was employed, e.g.
>   Miss Ethel (Smith).

*Mrs* is not recorded as ever having been followed by a given name.

Comment: I have friends who want their children to call me Mr. Roger.  I find it to be encouraging incorrect use of the title - unnecessarily teaching a child one version of English as a child and then waiting until later in life to reteach them the correct use.  I don't want to be a part of that miseducation and reeducation. I know its meant as a sign of respect that is somewhere between using only a first name and Mr 'Last name' but strictly speaking I don't believe it is correct. I am an Englishman living in the southern US an I'm fighting an uphill battle!

Comment: ...and rather counterintuitively I think the phrase infantises (sp?) the recipient, although this is not my major concern!

Comment: perhaps you could help with my 'bring' vs. 'take' question I posted a few minutes ago. I just looked at your impressive credentials.

Comment: There are many varieties of English, and no one of them is any more 'correct' than another. Are the children who address you in this way American? If that is how they are accustommed to address adults, then I'm afraid it's a battle you can't win. Even if they're not, I can see no harm in the practice.

Comment: Barrie, I understand we have an evolving language, but if one version is not more correct than another then what's the point of this Web site?  For example, now that it seems many Americans blur 'bring' and 'take' can I assume they are both correct in all forms? Surely there must be some concrete rules?

Comment: @RogerSPearce: Rules come from the way speakers use the language, not the other way round. This was well expressed by the nineteenth century philologist Henry Sweet when he wrote ‘the rules of grammar have no value except as statements of facts: whatever is in general use in a language is for that very reason grammatically correct.'  This applies not only to English. The same was said much earlier of Latin by John Colet: 'Latin speech was before the rules, and not the rules before the Latin speech.’

Comment: In Texas, it has become conventional to refer to teachers and other adult authority figures as Ms./Mr. Givenname. It would not surprise me if this usage were prevalent throughout the South.

Comment: @MetaEd: In the UK the same applies to knights of the realm. It's 'Sir John', not 'Sir Smith'.

Comment: Around here (VA, US), i don't hear "Mr" or "Mrs" being used with just the first name.  However, i do hear a lot of use of "Miss" that way.

Comment: Oh -- I should have written "for children to".

Comment: I'm a teacher in NJ, and students must refer to us as Mr/Mrs/Dr <Last Name> at school. But I'm also in the same boat as Roger, where parents of my private students want them to call me "Mr. Jimi" at home. I don't encourage it. I don't think it's incorrect, though. I've heard several other interesting examples.

Comment: @Roger: As an aside, I think it would be more helpful if you pasted your first comment into your question for more background.

Comment: Thank you all for you're help. Barrie has led the charge to make me a less strict user of the English language and to accept it's evolution as our tool to meet our needs - not as our master.  I'm not happy about it as I enjoy being an English snob, but there are plenty of examples of myself taking liberties with the language so I should not discourage this by others.

Comment: You wouldn’t see Mrs Mary written, but once upon a time you could certainly hear Mistress Mary, and so it was written.

Comment: @RogerSPearce - can you not persuade them to use 'uncle' instead? Honorary uncles and aunts (unrelated persons) have always existed in England as a sort of halfway house between 'Mr. Pearce' and 'Roger' for the children of friends/associates to use.

Comment: I my cultural background (NZ, 1970's) this manner of address would be a faux formality used when addressing a friend and "wanting to make a point", including an adult addressing a related child. So as an adult I find it rather insulting to be addressed in this way by a stranger. The most common way I've experienced this is from call centre staff in based in India, where I presume it's a common middle-ground politeness; even when I ask them to address me otherwise, they say they've been _instructed_ to address me in this way. Like @bamboo I would accept "Uncle" or "Aunt" with a given name

Answer (score 9):

Short answer: no. I teach English in Poland and I hear this all the time as it is L2 interference from the Polish use of "Pan [first name]". No native speaker teacher of my acquaintance would accept "Mr John" as being correct and I don't either and I have *never* heard a native speaker say this (British English).

Comment: While this answer could, by the usual standards of this site, be subject to criticism as somewhat heavy-handed, it is badly needed on this page to make it less likely that the casual visitors will be misled by the most highly upvoted answer, which is in its entirety devoted to a regional exception to the usage that prevails in most of the English-speaking world, without ever stating what the prevailing usage is.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to have been in British English up to the Victorian era (perhaps later) as a way to avoid ambiguity when talking about members of the same family, who have the same last name.  A younger family member would be addressed with an honorific and his or her first name.

As an example, Arthur Conan Doyle's short story "The Reigate Squires" (1893) includes two characters named Cunningham, a father and son.  The father is addressed as "Mr. Cunningham," but the son is referred to as "Mr. Alec Cunningham" or just "Mister Alec."

Comment: I think this confuses two usages. "Miss Grace Cunningham" was the correct form of address for a younger daughter ("Miss Cunningham" would be her elder sister), but only a servant would address her as "Miss Grace".

Comment: @TimLymington: "Only a servant": I'm not sure about that.  In "The Reigate Squires", "Mister Alec" is referred to as such by both Sherlock Holmes and Inspector Forrester, neither of them servants.  For another citation, I looked at *Pride and Prejudice* (1813). Elizabeth Bennet is addressed (to her face) as "Miss Eliza" by Sir William Lucas (I.VI), and as "Miss Elizabeth" by Mr. Collins (I.XVII) and Miss Bingley (I.XVIII).

Answer (score 3):

Other answerers have noted that the form *Mr. [First Name]* is especially common in the U.S. South and as a way for children to address adults who aren't related to them. But I don't think that anyone has pointed out that *Mister [First Name]*, *Miss [First Name]*, etc., were a standard way for African American slaves (and later, servants) in the South to address their masters (and later, employers).

In its heyday, the form was used even when the master (or member of the master's family) was much younger than the slave. It served as a sign of respect for and subordination to the more powerful person in the societal hierarchy, so it unavoidably included an element of reinforcement of the existing social order.

Much later, the epithet *Mister Charlie* (as in James Baldwin's 1964 play *Blues for Mister Charlie*) emerged as a mocking way for African Americans to refer to a white man—a kind of bitter invocation of the old subservience. Harold Wentworth & Stuart Flexner, *Dictionary of American Slang* (1960) notes this usage:

> **Mister Charlie** A white man. *Some Negro use.*

Just because a form of address has unfortunate associations with an oppressive past doesn't mean that people who use the form today are nostalgic for that past or are aware of any vestiges of the form's old meaning that may remain. But I wouldn't care to call someone *Mr. [First Name]* or be called *Mr. [First Name]* by someone, because I don't like the lack of reciprocity inherent in its form.

Answer (score 2):

Say

> Mr/Ms ( last name ) ---- Travolta

or

> Mr/ Ms (first+ last name ) -------John Travolta

but don't say "Mr/ Ms ( first name ) ---- John". This is completely wrong.

Comment: I don't know why someone would downvote this answer!
Whoever it is, can you please justify?

Comment: I wasn't the one who downvoted but I imagine it was because it doesn't answer the question with any more than "no", which isn't helpful. Some justification for the "no" would be more useful / instructive. I also think it's wrong since the use is common (and acceptable) in the southern U.S.

Comment: I think this is a good answer, I don't want a long verbose answer that tell me a lot of special case that I can use Mr + first name. I just want the common case.

Answer (score 1):

I would say the answer is *yes*, but the only time I hear it is from children addressing an adult in a setting where there is a combination of showing respect (hence the honorific) and at the same time familiarity (hence the first, not last, name).

The best example is a children's Sunday School class: I know a "Mr. Joe" who goes by that name because he's been teaching SS forever, so there is a whole generation of people who call him that, even as adults, since they can't drop the habit.

Answer (score 0):

Mr. is most typically used with either the man's last name alone, or last name and selected other parts of the name. But that is for polite society. In everyday use, it is often appended to the front of a simple first name to lend a small air of seriousness or respect to what otherwise would be a casual use of the first name alone. **You particularly hear this with teachers.**

The correct way to use Mrs. is to follow it with the *husband's* name. So if you are referring to the wife of Fred Marks, the title would be "Mrs Marks" or "Mrs Fred Marks", **but never "Mrs Anne"** (or, heaven forbid, "Mrs Anne Marks").

That is a bit awkward (not to mention the uncomfortable social implications), so a lot of folks these days prefer to address women with Ms., a title that is used just like Mr., and carries no implications of knowledge of past, present, or future marital status.

To save you from finding out the hard way, I should also mention that there are some women who have very strong opinions on the Mrs/Ms address to use for them. To make matters more confusing, some of the former camp nonetheless expect you to use their "Mrs." in the same manner as the modern "Ms."

Comment: IMHO you should either have to pick Mrs. (as originally designed with all its drawbacks) or Ms., rather than insist folks use Mrs incorrectly for you. Otherwise we are open to an impossibility of figuring out who you are talking to with a "Mrs Femalename" person in a world that allows gay marriage..

Comment: 40 years ago, "Mrs Anne Marks" would have suggested she was a divorcée.  Usage has changed since then.

Comment: "Mrs" + husband's full name is truly a relic of the past, at least in the countries I've inhabited. No woman in my entire life has desired to be addressed in this manner, including those of my mother and grandmother generations, now spanning back over a century.